# "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 568

Tags: python, nginx, python-requests

I have a Python API that run on a linux server with nginx service. When I have added to my code the library `requests` give me internal server error with this error in the access log:

> ""GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 568......"
> "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 568 ....."

But my code doesn't have a html part and obviously doesn't use favicon, can anyone help me?

I don't want to change type of http request for my API, I tried to change nginx with waitress service and work but waitress have lezz slot then nginx so I wanna use nginx.

Comment: Error 502 is Bad Gateway error, probably missconfiguration on the server, is the IP on those log lines yours? If you're using requests and not calling those urls directly maybe it's not you?

Comment: Let's see the code you're struggling with

Comment: Did you test your URL with a browser?  That would cause this.  The browser will fetch the root page, and then tries to fetch the favicon.  If your users won't do this, then there's no need to worry about it.

Comment: There's way too little info here to determine what's wrong. Please provide a [mcve]. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].